# Jack2 internal audio routing in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: audio, jack, audio-route

I am trying to accomplish the following in Ubuntu 14.04.

I have installed the SIP client Linphone and want to connect its audio to Adobe Connect that runs in a browser (Firefox, for instance). So what I need is a two-way communication such that:

Linphone audio output --> Adobe Connect audio input

Adobe Connect audio output --> Linphone audio input

I have understood that Jack2 (http://jackaudio.org/) is supposed to be able to route audio in between different applications. I guess what I have to do here is to configure it so that all the audio that comes from Firefox is routed to Linphone's input and all the audio that comes from Linphone is routed to Firefox's input.

I succeeded in installing Jack2 with QjackCtl but I am unable to configure it. When going to "Connect -> Audio" I was expecting to be able to select between the various running applications in order to reroute the audio. Instead, what I can do is only to connect my microphone's input to either of my speakers.

What would be the right workflow to follow here? Do I have to configure some virtual microphones/speakers to make it work? If so, how?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.